# Seaborn -xtick labels in KDE plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Ive created a simple histogram/KDE plot with seaborn and Im trying to add custom labels to the x-axis as follows:

```
plt.title("Cond Density")
plt.xlabel("Cond")
plt.ylabel("Density")
plt.xticks = (['Bob','Alex','Steve','Gwen','Darren'])
sns.distplot(rawData['Conditions'], bins=20)
sns.kdeplot(rawData['Conditions'], shade=True)
plt.show()
```

There are only 5 int elements in rawData['Conditions'], but the x-axis justs reflects the values in rawData['Conditions'], which are just [0,1,2,3,4].

What am I missing?

Comment: [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Histograms need sequential ticks. I'm unsure as to what you're exactly trying to plot, but if you want to graph the density relative to each of these names, a bar graph would be best.